# Expand spreadsheet ranges to lists of cells in Scala

Tags: interview-questions, functional-programming, scala

**Problem**

Spreadsheet cells are referenced by column and row identifiers. Columns are labeled with alphabetical characters, starting with "A", "B", "C", ...; rows are numbered from 1 in ascending order.  Write a function that takes in a string identifying a range of cells in a spreadsheet and returns an ordered list of cells which compose that range.

Example:

```
"A3:D5" -> ["A3", "A4", "A5", "B3", "B4", "B5", "C3", "C4", "C5", "D3", "D4", "D5"]
"A3:D4" -> ["A3", "A4", "B3", "B4", "B5", "C3", "C4", "C5", "D3", "D4"]
```

Here is scala implementation of the same ,

```
import scala.language.postfixOps

object PrintSpreadSheet extends App {

  val validAlphabets = ('A' to 'Z').toSeq

  def cells(range: String): Seq[String] = {
    val corners = (range split ":") flatMap { corner =>
      Seq(corner.head, corner.last)
    }
    val rows = (corners filter (r => validAlphabets.contains(r))) sorted
    val cols = (corners filter (c => !validAlphabets.contains(c))) sorted

    (rows.head to rows.last) flatMap { r =>
      (cols.head to cols.last) map { c =>
        r.toString + ":" + c.toString
      }
    }
  }
  cells("A1:D5") foreach println
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get your code to compile until I took out the `sorted`. The output was still good so I don't know what purpose it was supposed to serve.

There's no point in casting `validAlphabets` to a `Seq[Char]`.  As a `Range[Char]` the `contains()` method still works. Better still would be to cast it to a `Set[Char]`. Then the syntax is more concise and the lookup is faster.

```
val rows = corners filter validAlphabets
val cols = corners filter (!validAlphabets(_))
```

Due to the use of `.head` and `.last`, this solution won't handle rows past `9`. There are also a number of input errors that it won't catch. These can be addressed if you use a Regex to parse the input.

```
def cells(range: String): Seq[String] = {
  val format = "([A-Z])(\\d+):([A-Z])(\\d+)".r
  val format(colStart, rowStart, colEnd, rowEnd) = range

  for {
    c <- colStart.head to colEnd.head    //from String to Char
    r <- rowStart.toInt to rowEnd.toInt  //from String to Int
  } yield s"$c:$r"  //back to String
}
```

This will throw if the input string doesn't match the expected format. If you'd prefer it print the error and return nothing (an empty `Seq[String]`) then you can use a `match` statement instead, with a default `case _ =>` for the format failure.

Notice that I use a `for` comprehension here. Whenever you see a `map()` inside a `flatMap()` that's a flag indicating that a `for` might do the same thing in a clearer/cleaner manner.

Comment: Code is compiling for me, here is same code in a online compiler https://scastie.scala-lang.org/eQxRuAvfR9qgCwNMiapGmg 

Also sorted is needed to handle  input like "D5:A1" , else it will return empty seq. without sorted version -  https://scastie.scala-lang.org/fD8FBWMDRRyzdvPvv4bazg

I thought about using regex and agree it makes validation straightforward. But I am not very comfortable in writing regex (specially in an interview), learning it. 

How about working with Strings and using some thing like this -

scala> ("A233" take 1, "A233" drop 1)
res92: (String, String) = (A,233)

Comment: But I do agree regex is best and I should learn it. It makes it super simple. 
I accept it as a answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're failing to handle columns beyond column Z (which should be AA) and rows beyond row 9. Your variable naming is also reversed: the columns are designated using letters and the rows are designated using numbers.